# Tkinter Grid of Labels with fixed column-sizes

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, grid, frame

I just started to learn python and tried to setup a simple GUI with Tkinter.

I am having problems understanding the grid feature of Tkinter.

I want to create a GUI, where I can dynamically add new frames with a fixed setup.
For simplicity, I just used labels in this example.

This is my code:

```
from tkinter import *

def newLabelWithContent(root, name):
    frame = Frame(root)
    frame.grid_columnconfigure(tuple(range(18)), weight=1)
    frame.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
    frame.pack(fill="both", side = TOP)

    Label(frame, text=name, borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=0, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=6)
    Label(frame, text="Actual", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=6, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=4)
    Label(frame, text="Unit", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=10, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=1)
    Label(frame, text="Type", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=11, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=1)
    Label(frame, text="Set Value", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=12, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=4)
    Label(frame, text="Set-/Action-Button", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=16, row=0, sticky="news", columnspan=2)
   
    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.grid(padx=0, pady=2)

root = Tk()
root.title("BaseTopic")
root.geometry("500x200")

newLabelWithContent(root, "First Element")
newLabelWithContent(root, "Second Elemnt")
newLabelWithContent(root, "Short")
newLabelWithContent(root, "Looooooooooooooooooooong")

root.mainloop()
```

The result looks like this:
[image]

But I want that all columns have the same size, no matter which text is displayed on the labels. So it looks more like a table. When the window is resized the labels should resize too.

Comment: It is hard to align those labels if they are in different frames.  Put all of them inside same frame instead.

Comment: @acw1668 Thanks, that did the trick. If you make an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is hard to align those labels if they are in different frames. Put all of them inside same frame instead.

```py
from tkinter import *

def newLabelWithContent(frame, name):
    cols, rows = frame.grid_size()

    Label(frame, text=name, borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=0, row=rows, sticky="news", columnspan=6)
    Label(frame, text="Actual", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=6, row=rows, sticky="news", columnspan=4)
    Label(frame, text="Unit", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=10, row=rows, sticky="news", columnspan=1)
    Label(frame, text="Type", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=11, row=rows, sticky="news", columnspan=1)
    Label(frame, text="Set Value", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=12, row=rows, sticky="news", columnspan=4)
    Label(frame, text="Set-/Action-Button", borderwidth=2, relief="groove").grid(column=16, row=rows, sticky="news", columnspan=2)

    for widget in frame.winfo_children():
        widget.grid(padx=0, pady=2)

root = Tk()
root.title("BaseTopic")
root.geometry("800x200")

frame = Frame(root)
frame.pack(fill='both', expand=1)
frame.grid_columnconfigure(tuple(range(18)), weight=1)

newLabelWithContent(frame, "First Element")
newLabelWithContent(frame, "Second Elemnt")
newLabelWithContent(frame, "Short")
newLabelWithContent(frame, "Looooooooooooooooooooong")

root.mainloop()
```